# String.Format() TimeSpan vs DateTime

Tags: c#, string-formatting, timespan

Why do I need to escape the delimiters when I format a `TimeSpan`, while it's not needed when I format a `DateTime`?

Example:

```
void foo(TimeSpan elapsedTime)
{
    String.Format("Elapsed Time = {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.fff}", elapsedTime);
    String.Format("Now = {0:hh:mm:ss.fff}", DateTime.Now);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the ":" character with a "\" (which itself must be escaped unless you're using a verbatim string).

> The custom TimeSpan format specifiers do not include placeholder
>   separator symbols, such as the symbols that separate days from hours,
>   hours from minutes, or seconds from fractional seconds. Instead, these
>   symbols must be included in the custom format string as string
>   literals. For example, "dd.hh:mm" defines a period (.) as the
>   separator between days and hours, and a colon (:) as the separator
>   between hours and minutes.

You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx)